# Windows phone 7 listbox corrupted data

Tags: c#, xaml, listbox, windows-phone

I'm trying to display information through a webservice in a ListBox which has `TextBlock` bindings. I've been researching this issue online and can't seem to resolve this problem. My database tables do hold proper data. Lastly, I've got a page that provides the same exact functions/methods and it displays proper data. I'm really troubled by this issue and was hoping one of you  out there could help out!

I'm unable to upload a screenshot of my ListBox but I'll try my best to illustrate it here!

> Purchase Order(Title)
>
> Purchase Order No: 1 (ListItem)
>   Status: Accepted (ListItem)
>
> -----Corrupted data appears after the first row has been shown-----
>
> Purchase Order No: 0
>
> Purchase Order No: 0
>
> ----End----

Note that my first row displays correct data whereas the others are all corrupted.
However, when implementing a search function, i'm able to view existing data from the database properly.(Not corrupted).

PurchaseOrder.aspx:

```
<controls:PivotItem Header="Purchase Order" FontSize="18">
            <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
                <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxPurchaseOrder" Margin="20,42,38,0" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalAlignment">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding purchaseOrderID, StringFormat='Purchase Order No: \{0\}'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" FontSize="38" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding status, StringFormat='Status: \{0\}'}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,-6,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </controls:PivotItem>
```

PurchaseOrder.aspx.cs:

```
public PO()
{
    load();
    InitializeComponent();
}

bool success = false;

Session.PurchaseOrder session = new Session.PurchaseOrder();

private void load()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    IfsRetailerClient myClient = new IfsRetailerClient();
    myClient.getPurchaseOrder1Completed += new EventHandler<getPurchaseOrder1CompletedEventArgs>(myClient_getPurchaseOrder1Completed);
    myClient.getPurchaseOrder1Async();
}

void myClient_getPurchaseOrder1Completed(object sender, getPurchaseOrder1CompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBoxPurchaseOrder.ItemsSource = e.Result;
}
```

Webservice file, IfsRetailer.cs:

```
[OperationContract]
List<Payment> getPayment();
```

fsRetailer.cs:

```
DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities();
public List<Payment> getPayment()
{
    return db.Payments.ToList();
}
```

Comment: What is "corrupted data"?

Comment: You should be able to take a screenshot from the emulator, just click the two arrows in the context menu that appears when holding the mouse over the emulator, and then click the "screenshot" tab.

Comment: Hi patrick! I'm unable to display a screenshot has i don't have enough reputation in stackoverflow!

Also, i've figured out my problem. It seems that my database contains xml expressions hence the webservice returns invalid data. Would you advice to solve this issue? Its most probably because my database contains dateformat related data. Eg, 4/2/2013.

Thanks in advance!